# ionic build --release --prod ios fails

Tags: ionic-framework, build, xcode8

ionic build --release --prod ios has begun failing intermitently and gives the following error:

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig
```

Any ideas?

Ionic 2.2.1
Xcode 8

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure worked for me:

- deleted the node_module folder
- NPM Install
- ionic Serve
- Stop server
- ionic platform add ios
- ionic build --release --prod ios